STM32, how it works when NRST is LOW?
I was wondering because I wanted to use SWDIO and SWCLK as GPIO but how does NRST works then ? I hold NRST button to take it LOW.
The MCU is in reset state and what works in that state ? GPIO are now reassigned to SWDIO and SWCLK ?
How when I have these SWDIO and SWCLK it resets the MCU without NRST ?
Should I hold this NRST while programing using SWD that was reassigned ?
BOOT mode is selected when NRST is high and not low so I am confused how this works step by step reading reference manual.

If you have SWD enabled, pulling reset low resets the pins to SWD mode.
You likely cannot program the MCU via SWD while reset is low, because the core does not run, and programming needs the CPU to run the programming stub uploaded via SWD.
When MCU comes out of reset the pins will be in SWD mode unless you reprogram them as GPIO so then they are not SWD any more and you cannot access it via SWD. Not until you pull NRST low to reset the pins to SWD mode.

But when it comes out of reset the flash code is running so why it chaneges into SWD for a while when I am physically not that fast to upload my code in that short while before my code changes it into GPIO.

@Mariatto You might not be asking why. It will because it is how it works so you can debug it.  If you yourself configure the SWD into GPIO immediately and can't use it, then that's up to you and your program to choose to do so and prevent debugging. To be fair, most SWD debuggers allow you to connect under reset so you can upload firmware, but then the hardware must not cause problems by driving the SWD lines, or work improperly if those IOs drive relays or mains motors etc.

I mean when uploading code from CubeIDE to STM32Nucleo it usually puts everything in RESET i guess ?
So I wondered if I want to change SWD into GPIO then how can I upload code again ??? How to do its step by step

I am fully confused how it is reseted but it still programs, or you have fresh new STM32 and it has no program in flash it somehow can be programmed using SWD even though I set SWD using CubeIDE and then I send code so SWD shouldn't be activated ... But it works ...

@Mariatto If your software is running and has disabled SWD, the programmer needs to reset the STM32, and then SWD gets enabled, and then you can use SWD to halt and prevent MCU core from running and then release reset pin and upload programming stub and let MCU run it. It's your uploaded program that disables SWD and enables GPIO when it runs, and that does not happen if it does not run, and the pins are returned to SWD on reset.
